# Validation of a dialog box for the update of fields "Mailmerge Fillin"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm looking for a way to validate those dialog boxes that pop up while updating a word document via excel vba.

The type of fields that I use is MailMerge Fields type "Fillin"

```
WordObj.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.AddFillIn
```

I'd like to write in them if possible too.

Update operation

[image]

Dialog box

[image]

Comment: You really should look at parameters for the MailMergeFields.AddFillIn Method. As for validating, you need to clarify what you're trying to validate.

Comment: Thank you but I haven't found any informations that I was able to use on Microsoft website.. By validating I mean doing the same as if I would press the 'ok' button of the dialog box. Thank you fo your answer ;)

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.MailMergeFields.AddFillIn

Answer (score 0):

It is by no means clear what you're trying to achieve. When you use:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.AddFillIn
```

the resulting field doesn't show up in the document until something is done to cause it to update (e.g. performing the mailmerge). If you want the field to show up, use something like:

```
Dim wdFld As Object
With WordObj.ActiveDocument
  Set wdFld = .Fields.Add(.Range.Characters.Last, -1, "QUOTE ""Default Text""", False)
  wdFld.Code.Text = "FILLIN ""Some prompt"" \d ""Default Text"" \o"
End With
```

Other than that, you really do need to both explain how and why you're using a FILLIN field and post the code that updates it when the mailmerge is executed. After all, the use of a FILLIN field typically means the user is supposed to both make an input and press the OK/Cancel button.

To allow the specification of different ranges, prompts and defaults, you might use something like:

```
Sub FILLIN(StrBkMk As String, StrPrmpt As String, StrDflt As String)
Dim wdFld As Object
Dim quote As String

quote = char(34)

With WordObj.ActiveDocument
  Set wdFld = .Fields.Add(.Bookmarks(StrBkMk).Range, -1, "QUOTE " & quote & StrDflt & quote, False)
  wdFld.Code.Text = "FILLIN " & StrPrmpt & " \d " & StrDflt & " \o  \* MERGEFORMAT "
End With
End Sub
```

where 'StrBkMk' is the name of a bookmark you want to position the field at. You'd then call the above code with something like:

```
Call FILLIN("FILLIN1", nom_signet, nouveau_texte_signet)
```

Or, if you're passing multi-word strings:

```
Call FILLIN("FILLIN1", "" & nom_signet & "", "" & nouveau_texte_signet & "")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain better the next time. Thank you for the piece of code you wrote, it's a solution that works for me ! I would have a last question. Using that piece of code you wrote, how could I replace "Some prompt" by a string variable (which name is "nom_signet") and which contains the text I want to use ; and same for "Default Text" --> the string variable I want to use is named "nouveau_texte_signet" and contains also the text I want to use. I'd like to use variables to be able to make this piece of code run mutiple times with different texts written in. Thank you in advance !

Comment: The new solution works with the edit I added (might be wrong...?), however I still have two poblems. First if I put a date ("2020-12-10") in StrDflt, the letter Ê is written in the fiels (ascii character I guess for 2020). Second, if I put more than one word, all words are linked together without spaces or linebreak. Do you know a way to fix those problems ? Thanks again !